# Checking Specific Brand SIM card Type Available in GSM module

Tags: arduino-uno, gsm, print

Can I program a GSM module to accept a specific type of Sim card to be ready by the module? If so please post something that can give me an Idea of how do it. Generally I want to lock the GSM module to accept a given brand of sim card to be detected in the Module but I do not know if its possible. I will be glad for any help offered by anyone on the platform. I will be glad for any help

Comment: write the software to work only with certain SIM cards

Comment: How can I do that? maybe provide a link were I could get some insight on how its supposed to be done